# Mongoose eachAsync: execution order of promises unexpected

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I am using the libraries mongoose 5.4.20, request 2.88.0, q 1.5.1, and deasync 0.1.14.

When using .cursor() and .eachAsync() the promises don't get resolved in the order I would expect. In particular, I make a request to the data base, and for each returned document, I make several external requests via an async series. The sample code is as follows:

Request Promise:

```
    function Request (options) {
        const result = Q.defer();
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                result.reject(error);
            } else {
                result.resolve(body);
            }
        });
        return result.promise;
    }
```

Async Series Promise:

```
    function Series (entry) {    
        const result = Q.defer();
        const errors = [];
        //Iterate over some given array
        async.eachSeries(array, function (doc, cb) {
            //Make some async request
            return Request(doc)
            .then(function (body) {
                //do stuff with 'body' and 'entry'
            })
            .then(function () {
                //Move to the next doc in 'array'
                return cb(null);
            })
            .fail(function (err) {
                //Handle errors
                errors.push(err);
                //Move to the next doc in 'array'
                return cb(null);
            });
        }, function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                errors.push(err);
            }
            if (errors.length !== 0) {
                result.reject(errors);
            } else {
                console.log('A');
                result.resolve();
            }
        });
        return result.promise;
    }
```

Mongoose:

```
    mongooseModel
    .find()
    .cursor()
    .eachAsync(entry => Series(entry))
    .then(function () {
        console.log('B');
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

What confuses me is that the final callback in .then() after .eachAsync() seems to be called before the promise in .eachAsync() is resolved, i.e. 'console.log('B')' is called before 'console.log('A')'. I would have expected, that .eachAsync() will wait until the promise is resolved, then pulls the next document from the collection and so on, and only at the very end, when all promises are resolved, the final .then() is called.

Any suggestion as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.